# get xml value from an NVARCHAR(MAX) column

Tags: sql-server, nvarchar, xmltype

I read many related posts and tried to get the xml value from a column with type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for any specific tags.

```
CREATE TABLE dataTable (RECID NVARCHAR(MAX),XMLRECORD NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

My XMLRECORD column will contain a data with tag like

```
<row id='1'>
    <c2>Account-sample</c2>
</row>
```

Below attached is a select query that I created, which yielded a CLOB instead of the actual value. Any idea on how to get the actual value? (i.e. Account-sample)

```
select b.x.value('data(/row/c2)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)')
from dataTable a
cross apply(select cast(cast(XMLRECORD as VARCHAR(max)) as XML) x) b;
```

Comment: If it's XML - why aren't you using the `XML` datatype for it?? It would be optimized for space and retrieval and would allow you to use the proper XQuery functions on that column directly....

Comment: Can you show your result?

Comment: @marc_s Yes i can definitely make the column as XML but this is just one part of my scenario where i create a view out of the table. That view contains the split value of xml as column while the actual table contains NVARCHAR as the data type for some other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below Query

```
select *, try_cast(xmlrecord as xml).value('(row/c2)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') as c2
from dataTable
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: This solution worked! Thanks for the input. if you could explain what's the usage of this function it would be most useful to the users.